# Send and received data to another system using JSON and save to database

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am new to JSON and PHP and I am creating a offline and online datasync system.

I have a code here namely (upload_to_main.php) that is in the localhost that passes data in my online database server this file holds data that I want to store in my online database server, now what I am trying to do is try to received it and parse the data with the, upload_from_branch.php file but I get nothing. Below is my code for each file:

Upload_to_main.php

```
    <?php
      include_once "../ewcfg8.php";
      include_once "../dbcon.php";
      date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
      ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
      set_time_limit(0);

      $tables = array('patient',
                      'tb_adr',
                      'tb_case',
                      'tb_casecomment',
                      'tb_comorbidity',
                      'tb_consilium',
                      'tb_consultations',
                      'tb_contact',
                      'tb_pe',
                      'tb_prescript',
                      'tb_prevcase',
                      'tb_resultculture',
                      'tb_resultgx',
                      'tb_resultdst',
                      'tb_resultdstdrug',
                      'tb_resulthiv',
                      'tb_resultxray',
                      'tb_symptom',
                      'tb_resultdssm',
                      'tb_dot');

 foreach ($tables as $table) {
   $sql_select = "SELECT * FROM $table";
   $result = mysql_query($sql_select);
   $total_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if ($total_rows > 0) {
      $row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC);
        array_push($row, $table);

        $data_string = json_encode($row);                                                                                   

    $ch = 
   curl_init("http://localhost/medicalway/data_uploading/upload_from_branch.php");                                                                      
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
        'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
    );                                                                                                                   

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    //print_r($data_string);
    curl_close($ch);  // Seems like good practice
      //return $result;
    print_r($result);


    }
 }


?>
```

And Here is the code for Upload_from_branch.php file

```
  <?php 

    $json_input_data=json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),TRUE);

   var_dump( $json_input_data);
   ?>
```

What do you think is the problem?

Comment: Try looking at `$_POST` instead of `php://input`. Your curl is set to `POST`

Comment: what do you mean @Justinas

Comment: @Justinas how can i do that can you give me a sample? im sorry i am new to this process hope you can help me.